# Extracting data from a YouTube playlist XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, youtube

*I'm a JavaScript and YouTube API beginner*

I'm trying to access some data from an xml file. It's the atom file generated from a YouTube playlist. I want to be able to extract the thumbnail, videoid and description of each video in the list.

Here's some js I've cobbled together:

```
$.get("playlist.xml", function(xml){
var videos = $.xml2json(xml);
alert(videos.entry[0].title);
console.log(videos);    
});
```

playlist.xml contains the file generated from a call to:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/playlistid?v=2
```

where playlistid is a valid playlist id.

The file contains all of the expected xml and it's converted to json (via JQuery XML to JSON plugin) with the line:

```
var videos = $.xml2json(xml);
```

The code at the top gives me the expected output, ie: the title of the first video in the playlist.

My problems arises when I try to access other pieces of data. The thumbnail, for example, is found in the xml here:

```
entry[].media:group.media:thumbnail[]
```

It appears that after conversion to json, the ":" are converted to "$", but i get errors errors when I try either:

```
    $.get("playlist.xml", function(xml){
var videos = $.xml2json(xml);
alert(videos.entry[0].media:group.media:thumbnail[0]);
console.log(videos);    
});
```

or:

```
    $.get("playlist.xml", function(xml){
var videos = $.xml2json(xml);
alert(videos.entry[0].media$group.media$thumbnail[0]);
console.log(videos);    
});
```

The errors are variations of:

```
TypeError: videos.entry[0].media$group is undefined
```

I feel like I'm not understanding something very basic, but for the life of me I don't know what it is.

Here's a sample playlist xml file, if it will help:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLjyIfAzy9xVUWYcLK54OPd1lDXzMROK_5?v=2

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the feed as JSON in the first place (the `&alt=json` at the end of the URL)?

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLjyIfAzy9xVUWYcLK54OPd1lDXzMROK_5?v=2&alt=json
```

You can add a `callback` parameter as well and turn that JSON request into a JSONP, which lets you send it with pure clientside JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**SEE EDIT AT BOTTOM**

Ok, so I added the &alt=json, but you lost me at the callback to turn the JSON into a JSONP.  Here's my current code:

```
var ytPlaylist="PLjyIfAzy9xVUWYcLK54OPd1lDXzMROK_5";    
var jsonFileUrl="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/"+ytPlaylist+"?v=2&alt=json";


$.get(jsonFileUrl, function(data) {
alert("Data: " + data.logo);

});
```

And the alert box says only "Data: undefined"

Now, if I do

```
$.get(jsonFileUrl, function(data) {
alert("Data: " + data); 
});
```

I get the entire file displayed in the alert box, so the data is there, I just can't access it. I've also tried accessing it with things like:

```
data.feed.logo
data[0].feed[0].logo
data[0].logo 
data.logo.$t
```

**EDIT: Not sure why yet, but this (below) is working**

```
$.getJSON(jsonFileUrl, function(response) {
alert("Data: " + response.feed.entry[0].media$group.media$description.$t);
});
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this is working:  $.getJSON(jsonFileUrl, function(response) {
   alert("Data: " + response.feed.entry[0].media$group.media$description.$t);
});

Comment: I hadn't been going deep enough into the JSON, specifically I was forgetting the $t. Also, for some reason the first few times I tried it, it didn't seem to like me using those $'s. Now, all is good and it works as I want it to.